# how to use for loop block in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, underscore.js

I want to return in a for loop in a coffeescript function. but transpiler issue error.

```
breaker = {}
nativeForEach      = Array.prototype.forEach

_each = (obj, iterator, context) ->
    return if (obj == null)
    if nativeForEach and obj.forEach is nativeForEach
      obj.forEach(iterator, context)
    else if obj.length is +obj.length
      # seems the for loop and return statement is wrong
      for item, i in obj
        if iterator.call(context, item, i, obj) == breaker
          return
    else
      for key of obj
        if _has(obj, key)
          return if iterator.call(context, obj[key], key, obj) is breaker
```

But coffee-script-redux says:

```
D:\dev\nodejs\node_modules\coffee-script-redux\lib\compiler.js:153
    throw new Error('expr: Cannot use a ' + s.type + ' as a value');
          ^
Error: expr: Cannot use a ReturnStatement as a value
    at expr (D:\dev\nodejs\node_modules\coffee-script-redux\lib\compiler.js:153:11)
    at expr (D:\dev\nodejs\node_modules\coffee-script-redux\lib\compiler.js:123:18)
    at expr (D:\dev\nodejs\node_modules\coffee-script-redux\lib\compiler.js:135:52)
    at makeReturn (D:\dev\nodejs\node_modules\coffee-script-redux\lib\compiler.js:182:35)
    at makeReturn (D:\dev\nodejs\node_modules\coffee-script-redux\lib\compiler.js:161:80)
    at makeReturn (D:\dev\nodejs\node_modules\coffee-script-redux\lib\compiler.js:165:42)
    at makeReturn (D:\dev\nodejs\node_modules\coffee-script-redux\lib\compiler.js:165:96)
    at makeReturn (D:\dev\nodejs\node_modules\coffee-script-redux\lib\compiler.js:163:91)
    at class$.exports.Compiler.expression (D:\dev\nodejs\node_modules\coffee-script-redux\lib\compiler.js:1094:20)
    at class$.<anonymous> (D:\dev\nodejs\node_modules\coffee-script-redux\lib\compiler.js:2325:86)
```

I thought I know coffeescript loop statements, but it had confused me around absolutely.
Help me please!

Edit: Actually, my code is the rewritten coffeescript version of underscore.js 's `_.each` method. Does someone can rewrite it in coffeescript?

Comment: Could you post the coffeescript as well?

Comment: @limelights it already be coffeescript. what do you mean?

Comment: Yeah, the source code. What version of CoffeeScript are you using? https://github.com/michaelficarra/CoffeeScriptRedux/issues/168

Comment: Could it be a compiler bug? I don't see a syntax error in your code

Comment: @limelights ok, I got it. my coffeescript is 1.6.3

Comment: According to that issue on github it certainly was for version 1.4 of csredux. Not sure about 1.6.3